# Sed or Grep to replace until end of line after pattern match

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I need to replace all the characters after a pattern match until the end of the line while keeping the matched pattern

```
    blhablahPATTERN1XXXXXX
```

should read

```
    blhablahPATTERN1STUFFI_WANT_TO_INSERT
```

Everything I've tried so far has deleted the PATTERN1 as well...

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
sed -r 's/(PATTERN1).*/\1STUFFI_WANT_TO_INSERT/' file
```

You need to capture *PATTERN1* and use `\1` in replacement string

Comment: I hate answers that are only posted to have the first answer and get up votes ;)

Comment: `.*` would match until the end of line, so you don't need the `$`.

Comment: @devnull Edited the ans. I thought `$` wouldn't hurt.