# Replace line after match using sed or regex

Tags: regex, sed

I need to replace several variables with new values:

```
  'database' => 'booDB',
  'username' => 'booUR',
  'password' => 'booPASS',
```

So replacing everything after first match of, for example, `'database' =>` would do. Following the advice on [Sed or Grep to replace until end of line after pattern match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619337/sed-or-grep-to-replace-until-end-of-line-after-pattern-match) and using:

`sed -r 's/('database' => ').*/\1test/' $SETTINGS;`

didn't work.

Expected result:

```
  'database' => 'newDB',
  'username' => 'newUR',
  'password' => 'newPASS',
```

Comment: Always give a verifiable, minimal input and expected output for your problem, rather than giving strings only you can understand.

Comment: If you are trying to actually *edit the file*, then you need to pass the `--in-place` flag to `sed`; i.e. `sed -ri 's/('database' => ').*/\1test/' $SETTINGS;`. Is *that* what you mean by "didn't work"? What result to you get, and what are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally figured out. The following line works as expected:

```
sed -i "s/^\( *'password' => '\)[^\,]*/\1"new-pass"'/" $SETTINGS
```